# JavaScript - Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript

Following code runs for the first control fine and fails for the second control despite being exactly identical:

```
if (document.getElementById("employeeID").value == "") {
    document.getElementById("lblEmp").textContent = "Employee Name is required";
    ret = false;
} else {
    document.getElementById("lblEmp").textContent = "";
}

if (document.getElementById("grossSalary").value == "") {
    document.getElementById("lblGrossSalary").textContent = "Gross Salary is required";
    ret = false;
} else  {
    document.getElementById('#lblGrossSalary').textContent = "";
}
```

Code is working as expected for `employeeID` control but throwing topic error on `grossSalary` control.

**Razor:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.employeeID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div id="inner" class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.employeeID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.employeeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <label id="lblEmp" style="color:red"></label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.grossSalary, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div id="inner" class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.grossSalary, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
        <label id="lblGrossSalary" style="color:red"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `@Html.LabelFor` ? This looks like more than JavaScript & HTML.

Comment: Also `document.getElementById("grossSalary").value` There is no ID called 'grossSalary' the name of the ID is 'lblGrossSalary'

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
document.getElementById('lblGrossSalary').textContent = "";
```

and not

```
document.getElementById('#lblGrossSalary').textContent = "";
```

in your last else block

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue could be the following:

```
else {
     document.getElementById('#lblGrossSalary').textContent = "";
 }
```

Change `('#lblGrossSalary')` to `('lblGrossSalary')`.

Answer (score 0):

you can only use the dot (.) operator on objects, so if its undefined or null and want the ".value" you will get an error.

I re-wrote your code a little but this should work for you! its also a lot cleaner :)

```
// first save the everything in a variable for later
// if the element with a given id doen't exist the "|| false" will turn it into a boolean false
var employeeID = document.getElementById("employeeID") || false;
var lblEmp = document.getElementById("lblEmp") || false;
var grossSalary = document.getElementById("grossSalary") || false;
var lblGrossSalary = document.getElementById("lblGrossSalary") || false;


// before accessing the .value check if its not false
if (employeeID && employeeID.value == "") {
    lblEmp.textContent = "Employee Name is required";
    ret = false;
}
else {
    lblEmp.textContent = "";
     }
if (grossSalary && grossSalary.value == "") {
    lblGrossSalary.textContent = "Gross Salary is required";
    ret = false;
}
else {
    lblGrossSalary.textContent = "";
}
```